# change argument names inside a function r

Tags: r, function, arguments, names

I'm trying to adjust the names of an argument inside a function. I want to create a procedure that takes the body of a function, looks for *x*, changes every *x* into *x0*, and then restores the function to what it was before. To provide an example:

```
f = function(x, y) -x^2 + x + -y^2 + y
# Take old names
form_old = names(formals(f))
# Make new names
form_new = paste0(form_old, 0)
# Give f new formals
formals(f) = setNames(vector("list", length(form_new)), form_new)
# Copy function body
bod = as.list(body(f))
for (i in 1:length(form_new)) {
  bod = gsub(form_old[i], form_new[i], bod)
}
# return from list to call ?
body(f) = as.call(list(bod))
f(1, 1) # produces an error
```

So far, this code will change all variable names from *x* to *x0* and from *y* to *y0*. However, the final output of *bod* is a character vector and not a call. How can I now change this back to a call?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Ctrl`+`F` not cutting it for you?

Comment: @MichaelChirico Well I'm making a function that outputs taylor polynomials (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Definition). So I input a function, i.e. `exp(x)` and it should output a function like `exp(x0) + exp(x0) * (x - x0)`. In between something with derivatives happens, and somewhere I have to rename variables. I am making an automated procedure (so it works for any input function) Ctrl + F won't do the trick.

Comment: I think you want `body(f) <- do.call(substitute, list(body(f), list(x = quote(x0)))`. Then edit formals too. Not tested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surely there is a better way to do what you are trying to do that doesn't require modifying functions.  That being said, you definetly don't want to be replacing variables by regular expressions, that could have all sorts of problems.  Generally, trying to manipulate code as strings is going to lead to problems, for example, a function like `tricky <- function(x, y) { tst <- "x + y"; -xx*x + yy*y }`, where there are strings and variable names overlap, will lead to the wrong results.

Here is a function that takes a recursive approach (`Recall`) to  traverse the expression tree (recursion could be avoided using a 'stack' type structure, but it seems more difficult to me).

```
## Function to replace variables in function body
## expr is `body(f)`, keyvals is a lookup table for replacements
rep_vars <- function(expr, keyvals) {
    if (!length(expr)) return()
    for (i in seq_along(expr)) {
        if (is.call(expr[[i]])) expr[[i]][-1L] <- Recall(expr[[i]][-1L], keyvals)
        if (is.name(expr[[i]]) && deparse(expr[[i]]) %in% names(keyvals))
            expr[[i]] <- as.name(keyvals[[deparse(expr[[i]])]])
    }
    return( expr )
}

## Test it
f <- function(x, y) -x^2 + x + -y^2 + y
newvals <- c('x'='x0', 'y'='y0')  # named lookup vector

newbod <- rep_vars(body(f), newvals)
newbod
# -x0^2 + x0 + -y0^2 + y0

## Rename the formals, and update the body
formals(f) <- pairlist(x0=bquote(), y0=bquote())
body(f) <- newbod

## The new 'f'
f
# function (x0, y0) 
# -x0^2 + x0 + -y0^2 + y0

f(2, 2)
# [1] -4
```

With a more difficult function, where you want to avoid modifying strings or the other variables named `yy` and `xx` for example,

```
tricky <- function(x, y) { tst <- "x + y"; -xx*x + yy*y }
formals(tricky) <- pairlist(x0=bquote(), y0=bquote())
body(tricky) <- rep_vars(body(tricky), newvals)
tricky
# function (x0, y0) 
# {
#     tst <- "x + y"
#     -xx * x0 + yy * y0
# }
#
```

Comment: Works perfect! Even solves another problem (one I forgot to mention) where some functions like `exp(x)` gets turned into `ex0p(x0)`! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to go here. Following your code, I would go with something like this:

```
f = function(x, y) -x^2 + x + -y^2 + y
# Take old names
form_old = names(formals(f))
# Make new names
form_new = paste0(form_old, 0)
deparse(body(f)) -> bod
for (i in 1:length(form_new)) {
  bod = gsub(form_old[i], form_new[i], bod, fixed = TRUE)
}
formals(f) = setNames(vector("list", length(form_new)), form_new)
body(f) <- parse(text = bod)
f(1, 1)
```

Comment: This works for the example, but unfortunately it doesn't work for `exp(x)` which I forgot to mention in my example. Still, I think I can make use of the `deparse` and `parse` for function body editing situations (i.e. pasting terms). Thanks for answering!

Comment: Yeah, the other answer is much better. I was mostly just trying to make it work following your setup.